# execute powershell commands from ruby

Tags: ruby, powershell

I was trying to execute a powershell command from ruby code.
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -ComputerName . -Filter "Name='Qlik Sense Client'" |Select-Object -Property version

It gives me the version of the product perefectly. But the same thing when i try to execute from ruby like(entire command in backticks) :
find = `powershell.exe  Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -ComputerName . -Filter "Name=''"|Select-Object -Property version`

The command breaks, it cant interpret the quotes, pipes etc in ruby. I tried to escape those quotes but it still it breaks. I dont know how to escape that pipe as well.
Kindly help me here or refer me to something relevant. Many thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have tested this now:

```
require 'base64'
cmd = %{Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -ComputerName . -Filter "Name='Qlik Sense Client'"|Select-Object -Property version}
encoded_cmd = Base64.strict_encode64(cmd.encode('utf-16le'))
find = `powershell.exe -encodedCommand #{encoded_cmd}`
```

Powershell expects UTF-16LE-encoded strings, so you have to convert from Ruby's encoding (UTF-8) before the base64 conversion.

---

Alternatively you could try using `shellescape` from [shellwords](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html#method-c-shellescape) to escape the command so the shell interprets it as a single string.

Another alternative is to use `powershell.exe -Command -` with [popen3](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3). That will let you write your commands and read their results using a file stream.

Comment: Thanks Max for the reply. But the last line where i execute the ps command is not able to read that binary as it it. Its giving like : "??????4??????????????????????????????????????????4????????? : The term \n'??????4??????????????????????
????4?????????' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, \nscript file, or operable program.
i tried removing newline chars etc, but still same output. Again, can you please give me an e.g of popen.My command has a pipe, so thinking how to pass it.Thanks again.

Comment: popen is definitely the most complicated way to go. The documentation I linked to has some examples. Did you try the base64 encoded approach?

Comment: hi Max,yes i did try that base64.The first line coverts it into some binary, but when i run the powershell -exe command, it gives the error as i mentioned above.Kindly advice if smthng needs to be modified.Many thanks!

Comment: @padmaksharoy I found the error and corrected my answer

Comment: HI Max, Many thanks, it works fine. Please do me one more favor. Can you tell me the reference so that I can get those basic information like the encoding standard you have mentioned. This approach will help me debug probs with a new approach unlike just google search. Many thanks again!

Comment: @padmaksharoy Sorry, I do not know where these standards are. I know from experience the default encodings of Ruby and Windows and I figured out with experimentation that this was the source of the problem for powershell.

Comment: Fine, thanks. I wanted to do the same with a command like
Thumbprint = %{Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\\LocalMachine\\Root | Where-Object {$_.Subject -match "CN=WIN-I5NP98N6JUE.cpteam.local"}.Thumbprint}
But here, it is not able to interpret that filter match part.Giving error like:
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBindingValidationException. Do i need to escape these baraces after pipe somehow, kindly advice.

Comment: just `puts cmd` to make sure the command string looks right. Ruby should understand brace-matching with the `%{...}` form of quoting strings

Comment: Hi, it wont print because its breaking inside the braces {} inside the command -->-  Where-Object {$_. , in this part. Error is like 

Where-Object : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'FilterScript' because it is null

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: HI Max, Just wanted to make clear that it prints till the encoded_command,(where we are changing to powershell standards) ,but once i execute the next line with powershell.exe, it throws error "=> "Where-Object : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'FilterScript' because it is null.\nAt line:1 char:60\n+ ... ot | W
here-Object {$_.Subject -match \"CN=PDC2LAP-705122K\"}.Thumbprint\n+                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBindingValidationExcepti"

Comment: HI Max, anyways i put the commands in a ps1 script & all works fine.Just let me know anytime if you can , the reason it did not work the way you mentioned. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example of how I shell to external apps, should also work with Powershell. Copy the working command from your console between the {} without extra delimiters. The %Q also makes it possible to do interpolation of variables in case your command is not always the same, it works the same way as between the " delimiter.

All the output is captured by the `" 2>&1"` and enumerated line by line in the block after while.

In case more than one line is captured you need to check which line the result you are after is displayed and return the result.

```
def powershell 
  command = %Q{your command just like you execute it in a console}
  IO.popen(command+" 2>&1") do |pipe|
    pipe.sync = true
    while lijn = pipe.gets
      # do whatever you need with the output of the command
      # return the result
    end
  end
end
```

Use the %q{} alternative if you don't need the interpolation since that also could give problems. Use the Ruby comamnd in the same console as where you get your powershell results. Ensure you can run powershell from there (must be in the path).

But as I understand this will get you the name and version of the installed products on your pc.

Why not use just Ruby ? It's way more faster than the VERY slow Wmi queries.

```
require 'win32/registry'

Win32::Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.open(
  'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall'
) do |reg|
  reg.each_key do |key|
    k = reg.open(key)
    puts key
    puts k["DisplayName"]    rescue "?"
    puts k["DisplayVersion"] rescue "?"
    puts
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi Peter, many thanks for the reply. I tried running  the powershell command as it as without any delimeter, like
  command = %Q{Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -ComputerName . -Filter "Name='Java Auto Updater'"|Select-Object -Property version}
But its not able to execute the powershell command.

PS C:\Users\padmaksha.roy\Documents> ruby cmd_test.rb
'Get-WmiObject' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Command works fine. Prints below.

version
-------
2.8.121.13

kindly suggest.

Comment: try with %q{} and also see my suggestion  I added, I can't run the powershell command you use, I allready get error in the console

Comment: hi Peter, many thanks again. %q{} gives the same error, cant interpret the powershell commands. The 2nd thing you advised does work but it is not giving all the list of products. Shall i have to change the directory to get the list of all products installed. I will then put some checks for the product i want. Will be grateful if you advice a little here.Thanks again.

Comment: just use the basic "powershell.exe Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -ComputerName ." and do the filtering and selecting of properties in the while block but it will be slow otherwise use the ruby method but search in the registry first in which key the required info is using regedit.exe

Comment: Hi Peter, I could get the exact details using the rub win32 Reg doing some iterations. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: glad it worked out, could you accept and upvote the answer please ? also it would be helpful for others to publish the result in an edit

Comment: Sure, I have done that. I wanted to use the same thing in  a chef recipe but it seems chef has a different resource registry_key. I was trying like this, but could not work it out.    
    ruby_block 'check' do
  block do
    found = "Qlik keys found"
  end
  only_if {
    registry_key_exists?("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\Qlik Sense 3.2",
    :x86_64)
  }
end

Comment: HI peter, the chef thing i will post separately.Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have accepted both answers as both are working fine & ruby is doing the work quite faster, not sure why stack is allowing me to accept just one answer :(

Comment: you have now accepted Max answer and not mine, you can only accept one answer yes, but you can upvote the other one or both and since you use my solution since it's faster ...